# import vcard in android 2.1

Tags: android, contacts, import, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to import a vcard into the android contacts. Within the contact manager there is an option to import a vcf file stored on the sd-card into the contacts. How can this be triggered via code?

Thanks,
Prateek

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer [android vcard string to contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599567/android-vcard-string-to-contact/4611520#4611520)

Comment: How is "Android source code is the answer" an answer? Is that really worth posting? And no one wants to contact you if they need help. That's what SO is for. If you have an answer to your question, post it.

Comment: @Falmarri... By saying "Android source code is the answer" I meant, the solution of this question lies in the Android Source code. The contacts import can be achieved by re-using the source code. So, if anyone is interested I can post the solution here and I will be glad to answer them in detail. I hope I made myself clear. !!

Comment: well that's not how SO works. As it stands, this is not an answer to your question and should not be accepted as such. It seems like you do have the full answer and are witholding it until someone comes and asks you. What if that's in 6 months or 3 years? And how exactly is one supposed to contact you?

Comment: Got it !! Will post the exact answer soon.

Comment: You should not reuse android source code unless you comply with the license - please ensure that your derivative work complies with the following link: [Apache License Version 2](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#redistribution)