# What is the mimeType from adding an intent filter for sharing a contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts, intentfilter

How do I register my app as one that can share contact information?

For example, registering as an app that shares pictures is done this way:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I googled it, and I was not able to find a "contacts" mimType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contacts are usually represented as vcards so the mime type would be set as:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
```

But Google has a contact specific [item type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE):

```
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" />
```

Comment: I tested them both, and only text/x-vcard worked. in what cases should vnd.android.cursor.item/contact work?

Comment: I don't know, I only used vcard. At first I was going to answer only vcard, but since the other one is in the documentation to, I placed it here so you could test also.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer. Do you also know how do I get a phone number after receiving a text/x-vcard intent? I only fonud the following post that shows how to convert it to a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659323/android-get-vcard-data-from-intent

Comment: This answer show how to transform it to  contact http://stackoverflow.com/a/4600085/562840